# Creating a receipt style in css

Tags: html, css

In part of my application I have a section that is supposed to display a list of products and their prices with the total at the bottom. At the moment it is simply that...just a listing and kind of hard to read.

I would like to doll this up and make it look better. So I have been though a few different concepts and thought that this would look best if it was somewhat styles like an actual receipt you would receive at a restaurant or store. It will be easy to read and a whole slew of other reasons.

However, I seem to be having a bit of trouble coming up how to accomplish this in just css. My ideal goal is that the text would look something like this:

```
Item ...................... $50.00
Item 2 .................... $50.00
Long Item ................. $50.00
Total ..................... $150.00
```

And obviously I will bold the last item on the list, but I'm not worried about that now.

To achieve this effect I have tried a few different way's including trying to use `display: table;` which I have never really played with before. So forgive me if I am using this wrong.

My html looks like this..and I would like to try and keep it in this format because a `<ul>` is not really possible with how this code will be inserted.

```
<p>
  <i class='first'>Co-Pay:</i>
  <span></span>
  <i class="price">$</i>
</p>
```

and I have tried something like this

```
p{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.first{
    display: table-cell;
}

span{
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000;
    display: table-cell;
}

.price{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

as well I have tried something with `text-underline`, but I could not get that to work.

```
span{
  text-decoration: underline;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? where the dots or the border-bottom can adjust to the space between the elements without having to set a width? I'm really trying to get away from width's because I'm not going to know the specific width for each element. Any help would be amazing!

By the way a jsFiddle to help! http://jsfiddle.net/5m5t5pcp/

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html

Comment: @j08691, I can't really use a ul would this still work with my <p> tag? I've never seen that before. If so, can you explain how to use it? To be quite honest I'm a little confused on how they are trying to say to use it. I don't know if that is the css behind a class or if I would build that css in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use float specifities and block element to fill space in between, **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ibjsd)**.

HTML test :

```
<p class="list">
  <i class='first'>Co-Pay:</i>
  <i class="price">$</i> 
</p>
```

CSS test

```
.first {
  float:left;
  margin-right:1em;
}
.price {
  float:right;
  margin-left:1em;
}
.list:after {
  content:'';
  border-bottom:dotted;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:0.6em;
}
```

Tune height and border to your needs. (pseudo element can be your `<span>` standing right after the `<i>` elements.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
.first::after {
  content: '................................................';
]
```

with an appropriate width and `overflow: hidden`?

Answer (score 0):

See the working sample in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/ygeu54my/

You should use pseudo-selector: `:before` to bring the dots.

HTML:

```
<p>
  <i class='first'>Co-Pay:</i>
  <i class="price">$</i>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p{
    clear: both;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
p:before{
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    content : ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . " ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ";
}
.first{
    background-color: white;
}

.price{
    float: right;
    background-color: white;    
}
```

Comment: I like this concept, however the background-color concerns me...because I'm going to be using this in different places so I don't really want to define that in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5m5t5pcp/2/) with one possible solution.

There is a holder div for three different elements - you can adjust its width as you see fit.

A fixed position div with a large number of dots is added and given a negative z-index and `overflow: hidden`

The name and price are floated left and right

CSS

```
.lineholder {
    width: 350px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.name {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
}
.price {
    float: right;
    border: 0px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
}
.dots {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}
```